# Inconsistency between “getent group” and “getent group <groupname>” – why?

Tags: linux, group, getent

## Question

How is the following possible?

```
$ getent group | grep docker
$ getent group docker
docker:x:600:
```

Note that the first call doesn’t return anything while the second one does.

`grpck` doesn’t report any issues.

## Some Background

This is on a CentOS 7.6 VM that I have inherited from someone else, so I’m not sure where its configuration could potentially differ from the CentOS defaults. As far as I can tell, the VM is connected to LDAP somehow (but I’m not too familiar with this …).

Actually I wonder where this `docker` group is defined. At least it’s neither in `/etc/group` nor in `/etc/gshadow`.

As requested in the comments:

```
$ grep ^group /etc/nsswitch.conf
group:      files sss hesiod
```

Comment: `grep ^group: /etc/nsswitch.conf` would help; it may be in an LDAP store where you're allowed to list all of the contents, but specific queries are answered.

Comment: Are you on a local machine with no external auth of any kind, or is your CentOS connected to say, LDAP? What does your /etc/nsswitch.conf say?

Comment: @Jeff I suspect a “not” got lost in your comment ;-).

Comment: Looks like you've got `sssd` (or `hesiod`, I suppose) set to look up LDAP/AD groups but not to enumerate them. If you're connected to Active Directory I would expect something like `getent group 'domain admins'` to deliver the list of AD Domain Administrator accounts. Take a look at `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` for some details.

Comment: @StephenKitt it did, indeed! Good mind reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jeff-schaller’s comment got me on the right track: the `docker` group is defined in the Hesiod database:

```
$ hesinfo docker group
docker:x:600:
```

As @jeff-schaller and @stephen-kitt further pointed out, it appears that Hesiod doesn’t seem to allow to list all groups (hence `getent group` doesn’t return them) but allows to query them one-by-one (hence `getent group docker` returns the group).